# Getting users LastLogonTime on Live@edu using powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

I am trying to get a csv file of all users in a Live@edu environment with a LastLogonTime, but I am having some issues here is my script:

```
 foreach ($i in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited)) 
      { Get-MailboxStatistics -LastLogonTime $i.DistinguishedName | where {$_.LastLogonTime} | select-object MailboxOwnerID,Name,LastLogonTime | export-csv -path "c:\filepath\UserLastLogon.csv" }
```

I get the error:

```
 A positional paparameter cannot be found that accepts argument       'CN=username@domain.edu,OU=domain.edu,OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=prod,DC=exchangelabs,DC=com'.
```

+Category Info: InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-MailboxStatistics], ParameterBindingException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Get-MailboxStatistics

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a problem with your PowerShell syntax in `Get-MailboxStatistics` call.

Should be

```
foreach ($i in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited)) 
{Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $i.DistinguishedName | where {$_.LastLogonTime -ne $null} | select-object MailboxOwnerID,Name,LastLogonTime | export-csv -path "c:\filepath\UserLastLogon.csv" }
```

Answer (score 0):

No CSV, but Eyecandy :-)

```
$LiveCred = Get-Credential -Credential admin@live-edu-domain.com-net

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $Session

cls

set-alias list       format-list 
set-alias table      format-table 

Get-Mailbox |
  Get-MailboxStatistics |
    Select DisplayName,LastLogonTime,TotalItemSize,ItemCount |
      sort -property lastlogontime |
        ft @{expression={$_.displayname};label=”Postfachbesitzer”}, @{expression={$_.lastlogontime};label=”letzte Anmeldung am”}, @{expression={$_.totalitemsize};label=”Größe”}, @{expression={$_.itemcount};label=”Anzahl Objekte”}>C:\liste.txt

Remove-PSSession $Session
```